# Search for a substring between certain characters at unknown index

Tags: java, android, regex, string, replace

I have a String such as:

```
<div class="photo-box biz-photo-box pb-60s">
    <a href="/biz/the-kerry-piper-willowbrook">
        <img class="photo-img" alt="" height="60" src="http://s3-media3.ak.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/rCz-uF_qwqyb5Nnq74JeVQ/60s.jpg" width="60">
    </a>
```

How can I retrieve the url

```
http://s3-media3.ak.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/rCz-uF_qwqyb5Nnq74JeVQ/60s.jpg
```

from this String?

I thought about **string.indexOf()** but the number of characters before and after url can vary therefore I don't know at which index this substring starts and this could be messy. Any best approach?

Comment: You've to use `jSoup` html parser.

Comment: Well... you don't have to use jSoup, but it would probably be a good idea. If you're not doing much more than pulling a url out of a string like this it probably wouldn't be that bad of an idea to use a regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org) to scrape/parse HTML from a *URL*, *file*, or *string* and use its jQuery *like* selector syntax.

```
String htmlStr="<div class=\"photo-box biz-photo-box pb-60s\">"
                      + "<a href=\"/biz/the-kerry-piper-willowbrook\">"
                      + "<img class=\"photo-img\" alt=\"\" height=\"60\" src=\"http://s3-media3.ak.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/rCz-uF_qwqyb5Nnq74JeVQ/60s.jpg\" width=\"60\">"
                      + "</a>";

org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc=org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse(htmlStr);
String src=doc.select("img").attr("src");
System.out.println(src);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use an HTML parser, you could construct a regular expression and used the [regex package](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/package-summary.html) to match the only the data you need.

Something like,

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<img.*?src=\"([^\"]+)\"",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(data);
while(m.find()) {
    srcUrl = m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: No problem.  Always good to have a couple tricks in your bag for different situations. If you are doing lot of different HTML extractions, @AVD's answer of jSoup is the way to go. For a single match or two, I like to avoid the overhead of an additional library.